# How can I change my pause button when I play other audio

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a simple audio player with [audioplayer.js](http://osvaldas.info/audio-player-responsive-and-touch-friendly)

I want to change the pause button to play when I'm switching to another track. I was able to get the previous track to pause when playing other one, I just can't change the previous track button to a play button. In the page I have more than 10 players

```
 $('audio').each(function () {
    var myAudio = this;
    this.addEventListener('play', function () {
        $('audio').each(function () {
            if (!(this === myAudio)) {
                this.pause();
            }
        });
    });
 });
```

Comment: I just edited my answer... See my fiddle. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand that every other players should `pause` when any play button is clicked.

Working [Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/Bes7weB/ze68oh57/)

**-----
EDITED**
*--Removed previous for clarity--*

Place this just above `</html>` in your **page**... Not in your [/libs/audioplayer/audioplayer.js](http://artlog.pro/wip/valijon/band/libs/audioplayer/audioplayer.js) script.

```
<script>
    $('audio').bind('play', function (event) {
        pauseAllbut($(this).attr("id"));    // Attributes the function pauseAllbut() to all audio elements "onplay".
    });

    $.each($("audio"),function(i,val){
        $(this).attr({"id":"audio"+i}); // Adds unique a id to all audio elements automatically... Needed for pauseAllbut().
    });

    // Function to pause each audios except the one wich was clicked
    function pauseAllbut(playTargetId){
        $.each($("audio"),function(i,val){
            ThisEachId = $(this).attr("id");

            if(ThisEachId != playTargetId){
                $("audio")[i].pause();      // Pause all audio tags IF NOT the one from which PLAY button was clicked.
            }
        });
    }
</script>

</html> <!-- This is YOUR already existing page end tag -->
```

Remove the whole `$('audio').each(function () {` from `audioplayer.js` (line 198 to 211).

;)

**-----**
**EDIT**
*(Improved strategy to pause all other audios, since you're using custom buttons)*

```
// Function to pause each audios except the one which was clicked
function pauseAllbut(playTargetId){
    //alert(playTargetId);
    $.each($("audio"),function(i,val){
        ThisEachId = $(this).attr("id");

        if(ThisEachId != playTargetId){
            //$("audio")[i].pause();    // Good way to pause, but has no effect on your custom buttons.
                                        // See the other strategy below.

            // «USING» your `audioplayer.js` functions by simulating a click on each pause button IF NOT the one clicked by user
            $(".audioplayer-playpause").each(function(){
                if($(this).prev().attr("id") != playTargetId){  // Check if previous element (audio tag) IS NOT the target
                    ButtonState = $(this).find( 'a' ).html();
                    if(ButtonState == "Pause"){                 // If button state is pause (meaning user could pause it), click it. Does ALL the job.
                        $(this).find( 'a' ).click();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

I [*cloned* your site](https://www.bessetteweb.com/valjion/) in order to work this out.

NOTICE that I used different audios to  be sure of exactly what is playing.
To test a multiple audio function with only one .mp3 was making it a lot harder.
You may download my .mp3 files, if you wish.
;)
ALSO, I volunteerly disabled the controls hiding.
It was in order too see the effect on the other play/pause icons.

```
// accordion
var next = jQuery('.my_music').find('.accordion-toggle');
next.click(function(){
    jQuery(this).next().slideToggle('fast');
    // TEMP DISABLE OF ACCORDION HIDING
    //jQuery(".accordion-content").not(jQuery(this).next()).slideUp('fast');
});
```

Your question was a thought one!
I now consider it well answered.
;)

**NOW, for your previous/next buttons** *(asked in comments)*

This is a good topic for a new StackOverflow question!
It actually does *nothing*.
I would try a similar strategy:
i.e.: simulate clicks on other elements already linked with working functions.
Try something and come back with relevant code if encountering problems.


BONUS ADVICE: You definitly have a «audio file weigth» problem.
You'll have to look for audio compression.

Comment: I think the question was about changing the play/pause icon, not about stopping the other audio.

Comment: The `pause()` method should do that... no ?

Comment: One would think. I can't find any reference to that behavior (which I would expect). In the API that was linked, hence my answer to do in manually.

Comment: Your updated answer looks like a better solution than mine, upvoted.

Comment: @Cptn_Hammer: ;) Thanks! Fair player. I updated again... Added automatic ID attribute adding. So it's a «one script» solution.

Comment: it seems not working for me(( even the previous track is not stopping. I think in my function need to do something that deleting from `.audioplayer` class `.audioplayer-playing` because this class adding to `<a href="#">` pseudo elements before and after for pause button.

Comment: Placed the script in common.js. Worked only pausing the prev. track. But need to delete the class `audioplayer-playing` from paused one

Comment: `play()` method is called again, on line 228 in `audioplayer.js`... May interfere (?)

Comment: I dont think so. Now everything works fine with your script. But the  `pause button` for prev track is not changing to `play button` when it stops. :((

Comment: Saw that too... A silly question :Is it always the same mp3 assigned on each clip ? Or same intro?

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Need to delete this class for the prev. paused track. https://i.gyazo.com/4ff935df8dcb859e03c5ff1bb31d1a00.png

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette The same mp3 for all players)

Comment: Ok... Supposing you're right about `audioplayer-playing` class : add this `$("audio")[i].removeClass("audioplayer-playing");` below `$("audio")[i].pause();` in my script.

Comment: `$(...)[i].removeClass is not a function` getting error)

Comment: Sorry... This class is on the parent element... Was clear in your snapshot, but didn't see. Try this instead : `$("audio")[i].parent().removeClass("audioplayer-playing");`

Comment: Cool!! Looks like *partially working*... Now try this ; `$("audio")[i].parent().removeClass("audioplayer-playing").addClass("audioplayer-stopped");` May re-enable the pause .... Because now, just can't stop it ! ;)

Comment: Arrg... if so... Have to add the playing class to the plyaing one too.. Hold on, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Edited again... Looks like `audioplayer-playing` was coming from the other answer try (??? Can't figure out why since I saw it commented out). The class that has to be removed is `cssClass.playing`. Can't see no `cssClass.stopped` or `cssClass.paused`...

Comment: From what I can see **NOW**. You should only comment out `$("audio")[i].removeClass("audioplayer-playing");` on line 50 of `common.js.` Because you get an useless `common.js:50 Uncaught TypeError: $(...)[i].removeClass is not a function`. I get no error in console when it's removed. AND play/pause behavior is working as expected. **----> The problem you have now** is *loooong* delay (~10 sec.) for the mp3 to start playing. And this is due to big file... It's a topic for another question. ;)

Comment: I patiently cloned your site... files by files... to find it out. See here : https://www.bessetteweb.com/valjion/ Tell me when you are ok on it... So I can remove this *clonage* from my server ;)

Comment: But in the link you give its not working)) when play next track ne prev. track is in pause but the button is not going to play(

Comment: Right... Next/previous don't work. lol Another thing! Look, we're messing out trying to complete/bypass a plugin you have... This will need more thinking. Have to sleep now. Since I have your *clonage*, I my look at this tomorrow.

Comment: It seems i fixed the issue) need to add `if($('#' + ThisEachId).parent().attr('class') == 'audioplayer audioplayer-playing') {
             $('#' + ThisEachId).parent().removeClass("audioplayer-playing")
            }`

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette What about next/prev button to switch the next track and toggle the accordion?)

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette thanks so much) for the controls asked a new question) if you have time to help,  join)

Comment: ;) Bonus advice again : Maybe to use "partial" song" would fix the weight problem. Anyway, you shouldn't play the entire song... Since it is easy to find the file direct link and download it without paying 99 cents. ;)

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Will fix that problem in future)

Answer (score 1):

From the [pages you linked](http://osvaldas.info/audio-player-responsive-and-touch-friendly), it looks like there are no images. Everything is done with CSS. With this in mind, change the class of the audio player to

```
<div class="audioplayer audioplayer-stopped">
```

In Javascript, this can be done as follows:

```
 $('audio').each(function () {
    var myAudio = this;
    this.addEventListener('play', function () {
        $('audio').each(function () {
            if (!(this === myAudio)) {
                this.pause();
                this.className = "audioplayer audioplayer-stopped";
            }
        });
    });
 });
```

Comment: i have no idea how to fix this, help pls.